# Animate to css specified width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a responsive css framework(Twitter Bootstrap) for my site and have labels that have a width specified via css. So they have a class of "span3". When the page open, I collapse them to a width of 25, but on rollover want to get them back to span3. Issue is that span3 is different width depending on the current media query.

Can I animate the width to the current value of span3? Right now, I just have hard coded numbers in rollover and rollout.

Comment: Seconded, please provide at least the HTML structure. This is a fairly easy task in jQuery then.

Comment: @MattBurland No, just I'm asking a question?

Comment: @samuk: No, you are not asking a question, you are making a vague comment about some problem you have and expecting somebody to read your mind and come up with an answer. If you can be bother to form a decent question, don't expect a decent answer.

Comment: @MattBurland Gr8, Thank u for ur minus vote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS transitions to do that.

If you want to use JS to trigger the animation you can add/remove class instead of `:hover` in my example.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls8e4/

```
<div class="col3">
<div class="button">Label</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.col3 {width: 200px;}
.button {
    width: 25px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
    /*add more prefixes*/
}

.button:hover
{
    width: 100%;
}
```